# How to drag elements out of a scrollable ListView using touch, without having to hold on the element [UWP]

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, touch

As it stands, the functionality to drag an element **out** of a `ListView` means that the user will have to long press or "hold" on the element in order to activate the drag functionality of the element.

The problem is that our live testing has indicated that this is far from intuitive for the end user.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869055/uwp-listview-drag-behavior-for-touch/36272049) with a few interesting ideas but the comments indicate that they couldn't find a solution in the end, and the last activity on it was 3 years ago.

Perhaps somebody has found a solution or workaround in the meantime? The context being that I currently use a `ListView` because it **must** be scrollable horizontally, but I need the `images` within the `ListView` to be draggable vertically and detached from the `ListView`.

Comment: What special needs did you have to change the drag behavior?

Comment: Simply due to our live testing indicating that it isn't intuitive enough. I'd like to avoid the "long press" and allow the user to simply drag the elements vertically out of the ListView

Comment: You can try raising a feature request for WinUI at Github - https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml - everything is done in the open, you'll just need to wait for the next version of the library to use it containing your fix

Answer (score 0):

@AdamMcMahon from the sounds of your post you want to be able to have the image items in your list respond to dragging on touch (PointerPressed) which by itself is possible to do and fairly straightforward by wiring up the listview item templates along the lines of the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate1" x:DataType="x:String">
     <Grid>
         <Image Source="{x:Bind}" CanDrag="True" PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed" DragStarting="Image_DragStarting" />
     </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And adding something along the lines of the following event handlers

```
private async void Image_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var image = sender as Image;
        var pointerPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement);
        var dropStatus = await image.StartDragAsync(pointerPoint);
    }

    private void Image_DragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Data.Properties.Add("myKey", sender);
    }
```

And a handler for your drop target something like

```
        private async void TargetImage_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Image result = e.DataView.Properties["myKey"] as Image;

        TargetImage.Source = result.Source;
    }
```

However, at the heart of the problem is that the scrollviewer horizontal scrolling and the drag operation interfere with each other and the typical kinds of workarounds that you might try in the PointerMoved event to test if the movement is in the horizontal or vertical direction are not straightforward to implement because the ScrollViewer swallows most of the PointerMoved events as described here:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/02/15/where-did-all-my-gestures-go/

So depending on the user experience you are ultimately after you might try disconnecting the two user interactions of drag and scroll. For example you could put left and right scroll buttons on the ends of your listview to provide the user a way scroll the list and reserve the direct touch interaction with the listview for triggering drag operations.

Code like the following could be used to scroll left

```
        private void ScrollLeftButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ImageListview, 0) as Border;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
        scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
        scrollViewer.ChangeView(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + 100, null, null);
        scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    }
```

Another option might be to introduce two modes of interaction with a button that toggles on and off the scroll mode.
When the scrollOn bool is true, you don't initiate the StartDrag on PointerPressed, when it is false you do. This would give the user both smooth scrolling of the list as well as simple dragging from the list but only work in one way or the other at any given point in time.

Perhaps based on the particular experience you are trying to provide your users you might be able to think of other ways to separate the two interactions for your users.

HTH.

Comment: Yeah this pretty much confirms everything I had researched prior to asking this question. Maybe it's time I faced the facts that this just isn't possible! As it stands, I have a scroll left + right button at the side of my ListView which does the scrolling for me, but it doesn't fit well with the rest of my application as I have many ListViews which don't require elements to be dragged from them, and therefor work fine with Scroll as standard. So having just one ListView which doesn't conform to the standard scrolling behaviours seems strange and unintuitive.

Comment: Yes, I would agree, consistency is an important aspect of good interaction design. Perhaps the "toggle mode" approach for the listviews that need drag functionality might be worth considering, especially if the dragging is easily communicated as an understandable "task" to the user in your apps workflow.  

From what I have seen with users in the past the older dual scroll -or- sticky pull off  for drag wasn't always that intuitive or discoverable either and often needed to be explained to users.